# When I opened my desktop computer, it makes very loud fan noise

Tags: fan, desktop-computer

It's been like these for months. I still don't know what starter it.

Comment: This is not a good question. You need to provide more detailed information.

Comment: It's just that. The sound decreases on the point where the desktop is shown. But sometimes I could just tap lightly on the CPU and the sound stops. I really think it's not the fan of the motherboard.

Comment: It is the fan!!!

Comment: No I mean it's not the fan of the motherboard but the CPU case itself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the fan. The problem occurs due to heating.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Ajay. I might be able to find some fans for sale.